# Primary menu items are dissapearing

Tags: menus

on my website, www.trutrade.org the primary menu items are disappearing after I click the first time any of the menu items. when I goto the second page, the menu items are not seen, I need to hover on the links and only then I can see the menu's. Can anyon suggest how to make them stay permanent? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the background color of menu and text color of the menu items is same at https://trutrade.org/abouttrutrade/. That's why, you feel that primary menu items are disappearing. When I add this code, the menu items appear in red color:

```
a.mega-menu-link {
   color: #f00
}
```

So, try changing the background color. It should fix your issue.